# IntelliJ shows warnings in Vagrantfile when using ruby plugin for syntax highlighting

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, vagrant, syntax-highlighting, vagrantfile

in order to have nice syntax highlighting for Vagrantfiles I installed the ruby plugin for Intellij IDEA.

Unfortunately, now I get a lot of warnings, like
"Cannot find Vagrant"
"Cannot find configure"
"Cannot find vm"

Any clue how to get rid of those messages, and mabye even better get a real check in order to support writing correct Vagrantfiles?

Thx!

[image: warnings]

Comment: IntelliJ does not know about the Vagrant lib so you'd need to import them ... and even though I am not sure it'll work

Comment: in intellij 15 ultimate edition with the Ruby plugin, I don't have this problem

Comment: hum .. I am using 15.0.6 ultimate too and I can see the same .. how did you configure intelliJ to know about the vagrant lib ? do you recognize Vagrantfile as a ruby file ?

Comment: Meanwhile I use IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.5 and I ignore the warnings with                         `# noinspection RubyResolve`

Comment: I recommend using JetBrains' RubyMine for Ruby, though I understand that it's not free and that might not be feasible for some people. Also, RubyMine has a Slack where you can get very responsive tech support; although you're using Idea and not RubyMine, you might get some help there anyway (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2017/04/rubymine-slack-guidelines/).